# How to make aerodynamically aligned items in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there any technique within Illustrator to reproduce such an effect (see attached) to align items around a shape, kind of like an aerodynamic flow?

I'm lacking vocabulary to describe this effect properly.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like mathematicas StreamPlot or streamlmeplot in matlab? or vector field plot? You can do this in a external software export as eps and read it in. You can no this with pylab for free.  You can also draw the isoparamerer lines and offset, then use a suitable brush.

Comment: I think that's what I mean, from a few example I saw googling what you suggested, but this seems to require advanced mathematics  and programming skills. Am I wrong?

Comment: I wouldnt say its advanced to copy paste known formulas. But yes it is a gradient field which certainly wasnt introduced untill my second year engineering math. Insofar as i am concerned its not terribly advanced but then you probably would consider even my regular trig equations to be advanced altough the concept certainly were explained in school.

Comment: Ahah, exactly. Not advanced for the initiated, but pretty advanced for someone who never heard of a gradient field.

Comment: ill try to write an answer when i have the kids out of the door.

Comment: resources http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StreamlinesForLaminarFlowPastARotatingSolidCylinder/

Comment: I'll take a look into it, but from where I stand, it looks like a bit of a learning curve! Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond and thanks to you, now I have a proper way of naming it haha!

Comment: Sorry forgot about this here are the flow lines http://svgur.com/i/5V.svg

Comment: And zoomed + denser lines http://svgur.com/i/5b.svg

Answer (score 1):

If I were to do this in Illustrator, I'd create one shape, then use  **Object > Transform > Transform Each > Copy** to move/rotate the shape, creating a row of shapes that 'turns'. Then, I'd copy the row of shapes vertically by the same amount (no rotation this time), shifting it left or right by a step with each row, to 'bend' the shapes around the central circle. Of course, this would require knowing exactly how much you want the shapes to rotate and in how many steps. But by using a document grid, it should be pretty easy.

Comment: yeah, I thought of something like that but I was wondering if there was a simpler way of doing it haha! might need to settle for this though.

Answer (score 1):

How about draw the lines with your pen tool and apply a dashed line in the stroke dialog - you can control the dash length and gap length. The result looks like that of a weather map with air pressure overlay.

Comment: I think it'll loose a bit of the organic feel as they'll all be aligned!

Comment: I tried it myself, looks pretty cool - formed lines in an organic pattern, like growth lines on knotted wood and applied dashed stroke, depends on the result requirement. the example the OP provided looks a bit static and like little compass magnets all lined up - an aerodynamic flow would form round the solid object causing 'ribbons/streaks' of air to bend around a shape.

Comment: Aerodynamic smoke chamber testing on aircraft
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_eMQvDoDWk